# When PXE booting Ubuntu live, does root=/dev/ram0 mean to run the image from its RAM?

Tags: boot, server, pxe

I have been able to successfully pxe boot an Ubuntu live ISO. I am wondering how to get it to run on the client machine. The behavior I am trying  to eliminate is that when I shutdown the pxe server the client stops functioning. Is there a way to actually run this on the client without it being dependent on the server? Also do not want to install it on client just run it. Looking to do this for 40-50 machines as well so would like to avoid running it from USB's. I'm still new to Linux. Here is my pxelinux.cfg/default file.

```
DEFAULT linux
LABEL linux
     KERNEL vmlinuz
     INITRD initrd
     APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=4000000 boot=casper netboot=nfs 
          nfsroot=x.x.x.x:/netboot/nfs ip=dhcp
```

Am I correct in assuming the `root=/dev/ram0` is telling the client to run the live image in its own RAM?

Comment: Please explain your configuration: dhcp, tftp, nfs servers are on different devices ?

Comment: "Do not want to install on client" and "run it on the client without it being dependent on the server" sound like pretty incompatible objectives.

Comment: Hi pasman. The tftp and nfs are on the same laptop. The dhcp server is seperate. The client boots up just fine but like i said once you turn off the pxe/nfs device the client just freezes up.